# I want Regex to pick Email Address for Multiline body content

Tags: regex, salesforce-service-cloud

I have tried my Regex:

```
SHIPPING INSTRUCTION CREATOR:(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Company:(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Co Code:(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Name :(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Phone :(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Fax :(.*)(\n\r)*(\s)*Email :(\s)(.*)(\n\r)*
```

Example Body:

```
SHIPPING INSTRUCTION CREATOR:

Company: CEVA FREIGHT LLC
Co Code: 806353
Name : Peng Her
Phone : 651-675-4000
Fax :
Email : Peng.Her@Cevalogistics.com

Text copy follows. Some labels may be blank
depending on quality of source data.
```

Here I need to pick the `Email:Peng.Her@Cevalogistics.com` to update the contact details in Case.

Comment: You have the email address matched in a capture group already, see https://regex101.com/r/a6OrCo/1

Answer (score 0):

here is the regex for email

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})"
```

Comment: I have too long bulk content with more than one email Address, I need to pick this Email Address from Specific Heading "SHIPPING INSTRUCTION CREATOR:"